# Cannot import .rptproj in VS2015 - says it's "Unsupported". Latest SSDT is installed

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to convert some older VS2005 projects over to VS2015 Enterprise. When I open any with a report project (.rptproj), VS says the project is unsupported.

> **Unsupported**
>
> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects.  The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.

Every  search I've done, the solution is to install SSDT (apparently formerly known as SSDT-BI)

I havs SSDT installed already.. when I download/install from here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx), it gives me repair/uninstall options.  I've tried repair even though I did not suspect it was broken.  There are no updates available under `Tools > Extensions and Updates...` in VS.

Where do I go from here?  Every solution I've found says the same thing, but I already have SSDT.

Any info appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Support for BI projects for Visual Studio 2015 is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/mt186501

<strike>There are two versions of SSDT available for Visual Studio 2015.  Only the "Preview" version (available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383.aspx) contains the BI project types.</strike>

Comment: Well that's just confusing.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Microsoft released the official version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/mt186501

Answer (score 5):

[SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx) (a.k.a. SSDT)

> Open Visual Studio 2015 and choose the Tools > Extensions and Updates menu. SQL Server tooling updates will appear in the Updates list.

Visual Studio 2015 comes with SSDT which is why you kept getting repair screens - note "SQL Server Data Tools *Preview* in Visual Studio 2015" is the older version